# Column to Row with grep command

Tags: linux, grep

[image]

How to convert that file with grep command to : You And Me Together

Comment: grep is not at all helpful to do this.

Comment: and then, wear what command ?

Comment: `fmt` and `tr` come to mind.

Comment: hmm, can use sed command ? or awk ?

Comment: Yes, they're Turing-complete so they can do anything that other tools can do — but not always as easily.

Comment: no problem, can u give that command

Comment: The 'rs' command can do this.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use `grep`, the following command should work:

```
echo -n $(grep . file-onecolumn) > file-onerow
```

but it would be better something like:

```
echo -n $(<file-onecolumn) > file-onerow
```

Comment: Can u give me another command ?

Comment: Why you need another command? To do what?

Comment: This is too simple, This to my practice task if it can't be too simple

Answer (score 0):

The best one is:

```
$ paste -s -d' ' < that_file
```

Depend on what you want to do, this will do:

```
$ echo $(cat that_file)
```